Override beamer theme with default inner theme
I would like to combine the Hannover main theme with a more sober inner theme like the default one. But the override here has no effect:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\useinnertheme{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Point A
    \item Point B
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

While changing the inner theme to e.g. rectangles actually overrides the inner theme:
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

How can I override Hannover inner theme with the default one? Isn't it a real theme in the sense that it's just how things started? The user guide puts it at the same level than other inner themes though.
EDIT: I know I can change templates, I'm just trying to figure out why I can't override the entire inner theme.

Which aspects from the default theme would you like to have?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Unfancier itemize and enumerate markers. I know I can change templates though, I just want to understand why I can't override the entire inner theme. Added a remark about that.


That may seem tedious to you
Ok, done, I wasn't trying to shirk but to focus on the important part.



"the default theme is different [...] as it sets up a bunch of templates" But then shouldn't the override work by setting those templates back (as you did?). Or is it that \useinnertheme{default} doesn't set those templates to begin with since there is nothing to set?


The default inner theme gets loaded by default, you can't easily load it a second time. Comment in/out the first inner theme in the following example and observe what happens:
\documentclass{beamer}

\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents

  \begin{itemize}
  \item abc
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Instead, you can either undo the effects of the circles inner theme like this:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Hannover}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[default]

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents

  \begin{itemize}
  \item abc
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Or just not change the inner theme in the first place:
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[height=0pt,left]{sidebar}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=structure}

%\useinnertheme{circles}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}
  \tableofcontents

  \begin{itemize}
  \item abc
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

